# How to show text over icon in JButton

Tags: java, swing, button, icons

I am creating a few buttons in a Class using Java Swing API
While using text and icons in my buttons, the icons are appearing over and covering the text which is vital.

Why is this happening (although text should be appearing on top)
And how do I fix this

The code I use is somewhat like

```
JButton s1=new JButton();
s1.setIcon(icon);
reprep() //method used
```

while the method reprep contains

```
s1.setText("Text");
```

I give the code in this haphazard manner since the method contains instantiation of other JButtons too which are facing the problem and the reprep method sets the text to all those buttons

FYI I've already tried changing the order of applying the icon first then the text and vice versa

Comment: One way would be to create a small `JPanel` with a `JLabel` over a `JButton`.  The `JLabel` would contain the text and the `JButton` would contain the image icon.  Another way would be to create an image with text added to the original image and place that text image on the `JButton`.

Comment: Read the JButton (AbstractButton) API. There are methods that control the vertical/horizontal positioning of the text relative to the Icon. You can use CENTER to position the text centered over the Icon. While reading the API you may find other helpful methods for future use.

Comment: @camickr I have to say I probably wouldn't have thought of that - that's a really good hint! 